# For loop and While loop to select values in C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Could someone help me to look at the code I wrote in C? It can generate numbers, but the if condition looks like wrong, but I donot know how to fix it.

I need to get some n random values with distribution and these values are in a special intervals, so I use for loop like below:

```
  n=10; mu=2; mu_plus=3; p=0.2;

  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
    x1 = gasdev(&idum);
    x2 = gasdev(&idum);
    z  = sqrt(1-p*p)*x1 + p*x2 + mu;
    z_p= x2 + mu_plus;

    if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
     {   
        Z[i]=z; 
        Z_plus[count]=z_p;
     }
  printf("%d %lf %lf\n", i, Z[i], Z_plus[i]);   
}
```

Where gasdev() is a function for generating random value with a standard normal distribution, Z and Z_plus are 1*n vectors. The results are mess, so I think that the IF condition must be wrong. Could any one could help me? Thank you.

I also tried the While loop.

```
   while(count < n)
    {
      x1 = gasdev(&idum);
      x2 = gasdev(&idum);
      z  = sqrt(1-p*p)*x1 + p*x2 + mu;
      z_p= x2 + mu_plus;

   if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
   {
       count++;         
       Z[count]=z; 
        Z_plus[count]=z_p;
    }
    printf("%d %lf\n",count, Z[count]);

    if (count >n) break;
  }
```

It can print out normally, but occurs an error at the end.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to bound the `z` between `+/-2.17`?

Comment: BTW: `(1-p)*(1+p)` is numerical more stable than `1-p*p`.  Code will get better answers when `|p|` is near `1`.

Comment: No. I try to select the value greater than 2.17 or less than -2.17.

Comment: How are `Z` and `Z_plus` declared? In the `for` loop they will need to be of size at least 11 (or more likely, you wanted `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`.)  Also, in the `for` loop, `i` and `count` seem to be possibly mixed up.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake; It should be like: '  if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
     {   
        Z[i]=z; 
        Z_plus[i]=z_p;
     }'

Comment: The variant with the `for` loop does not set a value to the corresponding array position when the `if` condition is not fullfilled, so you have to use the `while` approach. But you should increment `count` only after setting the array value, as `count` will be one off otherwise and equal to `n` on the last iteration.

Comment: I made changes to ' double Z[10]; double Z_plus[10]' , and in the while loop, change the If statement as  ' if  if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
   {         Z[count]=z; Z_plus[count]=z_p; count++;
    }  ' But the problem still exist.

Comment: Do you initialize `count` to 0?

Comment: Your indentation does not look quite correct. You should edit to make sure that you are using all spaces and no tabs.. The break in the second example (while) would not be needed as the while should exit when` count == n`

Comment: The `printf` also belongs in the `if` statement, otherwise, when the current value is out of range, it will repeat the previous in-range value if there was one, or junk if there was none.

Comment: Yes, I initialize count=0;

Comment: Even I do not use the printf statement, the error still shows up "x.exe has stopped working". But it does show all the results.

Answer (score 1):

The error here is that you always increment i as part of the for loop so that if z is outside the range of the bracket set, you do not put any value into the Z array. You do not specify count so was that supposed to be i or not?

```
  n=10; mu=2; mu_plus=3; p=0.2;

  for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
      x1 = gasdev(&idum);
      x2 = gasdev(&idum);
      z  = sqrt(1-p*p)*x1 + p*x2 + mu;
      z_p= x2 + mu_plus;

      if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
       {   
          Z[i]=z; 
          Z_plus[count]=z_p; // Should this be Z_plus[i] ??
       }
      // Note that if outside of bracket no value put in Z[i]
      // This makes Z[i] and Z_plus[i] garbage
      printf("%d %lf %lf\n", i, Z[i], Z_plus[i]);   
    }
```

Your while loop is not correct either as it increments count when it is n-1 and tries to process Z[n] when it appears that you must have defined it as an array of size n (max index is n-1). Also the print needs to be inside the if not outside.

```
   while(count < n)
    {
      x1 = gasdev(&idum);
      x2 = gasdev(&idum);
      z  = sqrt(1-p*p)*x1 + p*x2 + mu;
      z_p= x2 + mu_plus;

      if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
       {
         // This allows count == n which overflows the buffer.
         count++;         
         Z[count]=z; 
         Z_plus[count]=z_p;
       }

    // This should be inside the bracket not outside
    printf("%d %lf\n",count, Z[count]);

    // This is not needed since it will exit the while at count == n
    if (count >n) break;
  }
```

correct code would be

```
   count = 0;
   while(count < n)
    {
      x1 = gasdev(&idum);
      x2 = gasdev(&idum);
      z  = sqrt(1-p*p)*x1 + p*x2 + mu;
      z_p= x2 + mu_plus;

      if (z > 2.17 || z<-2.17) 
       {
         Z[count]=z; 
         Z_plus[count]=z_p;
         printf("%d %lf\n",count, Z[count]);
         count++;         
       }
  }
```